# Proof that function has a maximal value

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that a function has a maximal value, the only problem is that very little is known about the function. The function is defined as follows:

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ as a continuous function

$f(0)=1$

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=0$

It is quite obvious that this function has an extreme value which is positive. I figured that I can make use of Rolle's theorem to prove that the function has a maximal value. The apply Rolle's theorem the following 3 things should be true I believe:

1) $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a .. b]$

2) $f(a)=f(b)$

3) $f$ is differentiable on the open inteval $(a .. b)$

The first 2 are true for the function f, but I'm struggling with finding a way to prove that the the function $f$ is differentiable. Any ideas on how to proceed with this proof are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the definition of limit, there is an $a\lt 0$ such that $f(x)\lt 1/2$ for all $x\lt a$. There is a $b\gt 0$ such that $f(x)\lt 1/2$ for all $x\gt b$.

Our function is continuous in $[a,b]$, and therefore attains a maximum in the interval $[a,b]$. It is an absolute maximum, since $f(0)\gt 1/2$.

Comment: This makes sense, much easier than what I was trying (failing) to do.

Comment: It is natural to try to use the Mean Value Theorem, since (for nice functions) it tells us all about maxima and minima.

Comment: And the same argument proves Rolle's theorem is true for unbounded intervals as well. You just have to replace $f(a)=f(b)$ with $\lim_a f=\lim_b f$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your problem from $\Bbb{R}$ to a compact interval where you know that a continuous function attains its maximum. Define $g:[-1,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(\frac{x}{1-x^2})$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $g(\pm 1)=\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x)$. Then $f$ has the same image as $g$ and $g$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ which means that it is bounded and it attains its maximum and minimum.

We know that $g(0)=1$ and $g(-1)=g(1)=0$ so the maximum of $g$ must be attained inside the interval $(-1,1)$. Therefore the maximum of $f$ is attained inside $(-\infty,\infty)=\Bbb{R}$.